# My import is not recognised suddenly, getting Unresolved reference when importing?

Tags: python, import

Here is the structure of my project:

```
poker/analyse_hand_river/analyse_hand_on_river.py 

poker/flop_turn_river.py
```

Inside `analyse_hand_on_river.py` I have the following import:

```
from flop_turn_river_cards import TheRiver
```

This used to work, but I think since I had issues with my Conda environment, and switched to a new one, it is not recognising the import anymore?

Any ideas how to test or fix this? Or how to set the root of my directory as `poker`? Which is what I think is the issue.

Comment: One step is make sure the path to the `poker` directory is in your `sys.path`. As a suggestion, review the [naming convention guidelines](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) in PEP8.

Comment: Ahh thank you,  I have added it now to sys.path, but the import is still returning the error

Comment: Ahh actually, I am doing it in Pycharm, not sure how to se the sys.path there

Comment: yeah even after adding it to my interpreter path in pycharm it still not importing it

Comment: Ignore me, it works! Thank you!

Comment: Better yet, make your code installable so that `poker` gets properly installed to a directory *already* on your search path (likely, in a virtual environment), so that your script isn't responsible for making ad-hoc changes to `sys.path`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As s3dev alread mentioned in the comment, you must add the parent directory (.../poker/) to sys.path via

```
import sys
sys.path.append('FULL OR RELATIVE PATH')
```

Directories that you want to import from that are not the same directory as the script you are running also require an `__init__.py` file. This can be an empty file but tell Python that it can look for modules to import from in that directory.